# retrieve the URL for a different language of the current page in prestashop

Tags: php, module, seo, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

Good day all.
I'm developing a simple module for prestashop, the idea is to be able to setup the hreflang thing in the backoffice, and inject the code in the header of all the pages. I'm actually struck at this point:

let say I'm on a page which URL is:

```
http://www.server.com/en/content/8-quality
```

from here, I want to retrieve the URL of the same page, let's say in italian:

```
http://www.server.com/it/content/8-qualita
```

is there a way to do it without try to search this on the database? I mean, this should be work for cms pages, products, categories and so on, I would like a way to ask Prestashop:

which is the URL of the current page in a given langage?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the page you want is a cms one, in the Link.php class, you have the following function :

```
public function getCMSLink($cms, $alias = null, $ssl = false, $id_lang = null)
```

Juste call it with the good lang id and it's done. You can call it from smarty with

{$link->getCMSLink('quality', null, false, $id_lang)}

Comment: that's awesome, thanks! but this solve only part of the problem, I would like to do it for all kind of pages, CMS pages are one, is there a getProductLink() also?

Comment: yes it is, take a look at the "Link.php" class from core, you will see every available methods